# PHP Check Function

Tags: php, function

I have a check function:

```
function checkCandidateEmail($email)
    {
         $email = $_POST;

        if($email)
        {
            $candemail = (SQL);
            if(isset($candemail['email']))
            {
              return TRUE;
            } else {
              return FALSE;
            }

            return $canEmailCheck;
        }
    }
```

I have started to create a function but I am getting NULL

Comment: What is `(SQL)`?  Is that a constant?  I don't think they can be arrays.

Comment: You're accepting $email as a passed argument, then immediately overwriting it with $email = $_POST; (the POST array). Is this really what you mean to do? Does $_POST actually contain anything? You'll get a NULL return if $_POST is empty

Comment: @Jess - $_POST (unless you're messing with PHP superglobals, $_POST is an array, one or more elements of which might contain an email address... but it clearly isn't what you think it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, elaborate more on your questions next time. I am not sure what you *attempt* to compare, if the $_POST with the SQL query or the argument passed with the SQL query. I assume the former.

If the email from that SQL table row equals the submitted email, returns TRUE. Else, returns FALSE. Really simplified version. Now it also checks if the user provided an email:

```
function checkCandidateEmail()
    {
    if (!$_POST['email']) echo "Error, please provide an email";
    else
      {
      $candemail = (SQL);   // Return a row from a query
      return $candemail['email'] == $_POST['email'];
      }
    }
```

---

If an argument is passed, compares that against the database. If none is passed, compares the submitted $_POST['email'] against the database.

```
function checkCandidateEmail($email=null)
    {
    $candemail = (SQL);   // Return a row from a query
    if (!$email) $email = $_POST['email'];
    return $candemail['email'] == $email;
    }
```

NOTE: In both cases you have to substitute `SQL` for the right string and function depending on your database.

NOTE 2: Make sure that your query returns an email, as this simple code does not check if both strings are empty.

Comment: You can just `return $candemail['email'] == $email`, no need for `?:` :-P

Comment: I was JUST about ask a question about a similar case. I realized of that while writing some other code, came back and just saw your comment. I edited it for the sake of KISS.

Answer (score 2):

```
function checkCandidateEmail($email)
    {
         $email = $_POST; // being immediately overwritten - redundant argument. 

        if($email) // Since $email isn't an optional argument, you'll get a PHP warning if it is missing, making this check confusing.
        {
            $candemail = (SQL); // Evaluating a constant? this will be bool 
            if(isset($candemail['email'])) // Since $candemail is a bool and not an array, this will never return true
            {
              return TRUE;
            } else {
              return FALSE;
            }  // this entire if/else block can be simplified to this: return (isset($candemail['email']));

            return $canEmailCheck; // this is an undefined variable and will never get returned anyway because of the above return statements.
        }
    }
```

Comment: the `if($email)` check isn't totally crazy -- it's possible to call `checkCandidateEmail(false)` or `checkCandidateEmail("")`

Comment: I suppose but it's being reassigned as `$_POST` so it should really be `if(!empty($_POST))`